# Does the romance and character interaction in Dragon Age: Origins and Dragon Age: 2 cut off like it does in Dragon Age: Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-2

After completing all of the main quests in DA: Inquisition your ties with the characters you love are totally cut off! It was really saddening to find that all of that relationship building with all of the characters was for nothing in the end. Does the same thing happen in DA: Origins and DA: 2? Or do you still get to engage in conversation with the characters you really like?

Specifically, once you finish the game, do you still get interactive dialogue like "What are your thoughts on blahblahblah?" or "How is our relationship doing?", instead of just pressing X and having them sputter out the same thing over and over?

Answer (score 1):

Well with Dragon Age 2 there is not 'after beating the main quest/game' setting as all you do is wander around you house, you can't go outside or go talk to you LI so yeah. Then in Dragon Age: Origins it's pretty much the same. You can't go anywhere or talk to your LI's after the game has technically ending. With both games you can play DLC that has it's own content and can have references to your romance but other than that there's not actually anything to do in the world.